How to prevent certain IntelliJ IDEA tool windows from closing from Shift-Esc?
I like to use Shift-ESC to close some of the transient popup tool windows/panes such as run/debug output or find search results.
I also have a permanent left-hand side panel split with File and Structure which I want to stay put - always.
After running a test or a search, using Shift-ESC is fine for closing the panel and getting back to coding. However sometimes I use the File or Structure panels too, then later hit Shift-ESC to close the "temporary" panel, but it closes whichever tool window has the focus - which is nearly impossible to see. So it randomly closes one of my "permanent" panels, upsetting my workspace which I then have to restore, click back on the "temporary" panel and hit Shift-ESC again. I do this many many times a day.
So although I like Shift-ESC, it's kind of spoilt it to the point where I'm now I've found myself doing CMD-4, CMD-5, CMD-3 in sequence to try to toggle the right one off!
Is there a way to perhaps lock the File and Structure panels in place so Shift-ESC will never close them?
Or is there another way to close the transient results? I don't want the "unpinned" version because it auto-closes when you click off which I find is more work.
I'm using PhpStorm 2023.3.2 on a Mac, but it should be a generic IntelliJ question.

Alternatively you could remember which number is which tool window, there’s only 10 digits.

I realised what I actually wanted is to "return to a default layout", regardless of which transient panels are open: database, run, debug, find etc. and without having to look at which ones they are and remember the shortcuts to specifically close each one.
This is already a feature: Window > Layouts - which I used to use but had forgotten about.
So I just saved my "normal" working layout and it by default makes the shortcut SHIFT-F12 instead of SHIFT-ESC.
